# How can values of char** argv be copied to another char **

Tags: c, pointers

How can I clone `char** argv` to `char** copy`?

- original - `char** argv`
- copyto - `char** copy`

Comment: Have a look at `strcpy`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: Hint: Try `memcpy` or `strcpy`.

Comment: the function `memcpy` could be a good start.

Comment: you can also do it manually with a for-loop as an exercise. Just remember that you have argc and that C strings are terminated by a '\0' character.

Comment: There are several answers to your question here, you should consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `argc` being the number of elements in argv:

```
  char** copy = (char**)malloc(argc * sizeof(char*)) ;

  for (int i = 0; i < argc ; i++)
  {
    copy[i] = strdup(argv[i]) ;
  }
```

Freeing the allocated memory once we are done with the clone, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Allocate an array of `char*`s the length of `argc`.
2. Use `strlen` to determine the length of each element of `argv` and allocate enough memory for each one. Remember to add 1 to the length returned by `strlen`, as this leaves space for the null byte at the end of each of the string.
3. Use `strcpy` to copy each value in.
4. Don't forget to `free` the memory you have allocated.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    char ** copy = malloc(argc * sizeof (char*));
    int i;
    size_t sz;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        sz = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;        
        copy[i] = malloc(sz * sizeof (char));
        strcpy(copy[i], argv[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", copy[i]);        
    }

    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i) free(copy[i]);
    free(copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `argv` is a `NULL`-terminated pointer-array there is not need to use `argc` at all.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* for strdup() */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int copy_argv(char *** pcopy, char ** argv)
{
    int result = 0;

    char ** copy = argv;

    {
      while (*copy)
      {
        ++copy;
      }

      copy = (*pcopy) = malloc((copy - argv + 1) * sizeof (*copy));
    }

    if (NULL == copy)
    {
      result = -1;
      goto lblExit;
    }

    while (*argv)
    {
      *copy = strdup(*argv);
      if (NULL == *copy)
      {
        result = -1;

        /* Clean up. */
        while (copy > *pcopy)
        {
          --copy;
          free(*copy);
        }

        free(*pcopy);
        *pcopy = NULL;

        goto lblExit;
      }

      ++copy;
      ++argv;
    }

    *copy = NULL;

 lblExit:

    return result;
  }
```

Use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   char ** copy = NULL;

   if (-1 == copy_argv(&copy, argv))
   {
     perror("copy_argv() failed");
   }
   else
   {
     /* Use copy here. */
   }
}
```